# QuickBooks Desktop Sync with Zoho CRM, Bidirectionally

Tags: php, node.js, quickbooks, zoho

I have the QuickBooks desktop app as well as a Zoho CRM subscription. The thing is I am new to QuickBooks and would like to have my data in sync across both of these. I use *node.js* most of the time but *PHP* is also an option.
Remember, I need to do it bidirectionally.

I looked up the web connector thing and yet I have no idea where to start.
Please provide a few pointers and libraries I could use.

Answer (score 0):

All development for the desktop will need to be done through the QBXML SDK. 
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/docs/0250_qb

To connect to a web application, you will need to use the QB Web Connector (QBWC) included with QB desktop. There is a QBWC server sample included in the SDK along with programmer guides for QBXML and QBWC.

If you are using PHP, there is an open source project available that has the server built and sample requests. 
http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/